# Github Action appleboy/ssh-action: How to add Go command

Tags: go, github-actions

Here, I'm trying to add go command when I deploy my app in GitHub Action.
The prompt in github action shows
`err: bash: line 15: go: command not found` .

**note : I already installed go and the `go` command works through my ssh connection*

I'm expecting the go command works when I deploy it through Github Action using appleboy/ssh-action, how to do that?

edit:
here's my github action script:

```
      - name: Deploy App and Deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.2

        with:
          host: ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} # IP address of the server you wish to ssh into
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}} # Private or public key of the server
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }} # User of the server you want to ssh into

          script: |
            export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
            source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh    

            export GO_DIR=/usr/local/go
            source /usr/local/go/bin/go

            cd /root
            cd go
            cd deploying

            echo "Cloning Git Repo to /root/deploying"
            git clone https://aldhanekaa:${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}@github.com/aldhanekaa/Golang-audio-chat.git

            echo "Building Golang source"
            cd Golang-audio-chat
            go build
```

---

well for example, for adding npm command on appleboy/ssh-action, we just need to add

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

but how about go?

Comment: Please provide enough information for someone to recreate the issue such as a Github Action configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) said, I can try by points the binary file of go command, but since `/usr/local/go/bin/go` is not short as go, I decided to add the go binary to $PATH.

So the solution comes up as;
adding `PATH="/usr/local/go/bin/:$PATH"` at the first execution of the github action `appleboy/ssh-action` script.

---

```
      - name: Deploy App and Deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.2

        with:
          host: ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} # IP address of the server you wish to ssh into
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}} # Private or public key of the server
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }} # User of the server you want to ssh into

          script: |

            export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
            source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh    

            PATH="/usr/local/go/bin/:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check first your PATH:

```
echo $PATH
```

If /usr/local/go/bin/ is not part of it, try:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build
```